# Skype effect injection?

Tags: audio, skype, microphone, transfer

Let's say I'm in a conversation with a friend, and I wanna show him a music but I don't have a link that directs to it but I do have the file. I want skype to transfer specific sound effects to the conversation. I don't necessarily need to be talking AND transfering the sound. Can it be done?

Comment: The whole idea of skype is streaming audio... I want to know if I can stream another kind of audio other than my microphone input... But Colin already helped ^^ thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

there's an open source tool (GPL/LGPL) which claims to do this: [Skype Audio Player](http://sourceforge.net/projects/skypeplayer/)